# Bitfield effect on size/type?

Tags: c++

If I write the following code, which compiles on Code::Blocks GCC:

```
struct ByteSize
{
   unsigned char Test:64;
};
```

A ByteSize struct has a sizeof 8. Which makes sense. But when I'm accessing ByteSize's Test, is it still treated as an unsigned char, or some other variable? Is this dangerous? Should I really be doing this? Will the compiler convert an 8 byte variable into a single byte char?

Comment: why you are using a bitfield in the first place ? There are high chances that you are just making your code less readable and even less portable using the bitfields.

Comment: GIF specification uses bytes. But there's no assurance a char will be a byte in size (they can be the same size as ints on some systems).

Comment: you are thinking in terms of char and bits in C++ ? It's like cooking with a camp fire in your kitchen. Why are you doing that ? What is your target ? If your target is to store a char just use a char, if your target is to store a particular charset be sure that there isn't already a library or a support for that, if you want to use a string just use std::string. Don't forget that with bitfield you need to care to every single bit, meaning and position, endianess included, basically with the bitfield you lost all the features related to data abstraction and primitive types.

Comment: sizeof(unsigned char) is defined to be 1. It's not implementation defined. See section 5.3.3 of the c++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

Clang gives the warning:

```
warning: size of bit-field 'Test' (64 bits) exceeds the size of its type;
         value will be truncated to 8 bits
```

Also, if a value greater than 255 is tried to stored to it, is gives the warning:

```
warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char' changes 
         value from 256 to 0
```

Then, trying to read from it produces 0. So, even though `sizeof(ByteSize) == 8`, it looks like it does just access it as an unsigned char, and it doesn't like you can actually store more than 1 byte in the member.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the standard, I found, in §9.6:

> The constant-expression may be larger than the number of bits in the
>   object representation (3.9) of the bit-field’s type; in such cases the
>   extra bits are used as padding bits and do not participate in the
>   value representation (3.9) of the bit-field.

`Test` is a bit-field, it is not an unsigned char or some other type. This is dangerous, because it assumes an unsigned char can hold 64 or more bits. You should not really be doing this. I haven't memorized all the conversion rules, but a compiler should not convert an 8-byte non-char into a char unless you explicitly tell it to (e.g. using casts).

...

Are you looking for `uint64_t`?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
struct ByteSize
{
   unsigned char Test:64;
}
```

is incorrect. Bit fields should only use a naked unsigned type.

```
struct ByteSize
{
   unsigned Test:64;
}
```

The value is unsigned so that there is no confusion about the sign bit. The field is treated as an unsigned integer of the field size selected.